# Cookies for kiddush

Tags: halacha, minhag, kiddush

Many people, including Chabad, eat cookies before shacharis which raises a question about kiddush asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/32161/why-does-chabad-not-do-kiddush-before-davening). I understand that they do this because cookies don't count as a seudah.<sup>1</sup>  The flip side of that question is, for those of us who eat *mezonot* before shacharis, how can we eat the same *mezonot* for *kiddush bemakom seudah*?

<sup>1</sup> Orach Chaim 89 (1?) forbids eating before shacharis. Mishnah berurah there permits various things and forbids others on the grounds that they are "like a meal".

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how many of the cookies you eat?

Comment: @Yitzchak, I took a quick read through the Mishna Brurra, and didn't see him discussing anything being like a meal. Can you find a more precise source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heter for eating cookies before davening is not based on the idea that it is not a seuda, rather that it is needed to concentrate during davening, despite the fact that it would otherwise be forbidden. As the Alter Rebbe [writes](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/8/89/5):

> ואפילו כל מיני אוכלים וכל מיני משקין ששייך בהם גאוה מותר לאכלם ולשתותם לצורך רפואה שאין ברפואה משום גאוה אבל לרעבו ולצמאו אסור אלא א"כ אינו יכול לכוין דעתו בתפלתו עד שיאכל או שישתה ואפילו עכשיו שאין מכוונים כל כך בתפלה מכל מקום אם רוצה לאכול ולשתות כדי לכוין הרשות בידו
>
> Even all types of food and all types of drinks which can create haughtiness, it is permissible to eat them and to drink them for health, as health does not have [concerns] of haughtiness. However for his hunger and his thirst it is forbidden unless he is unable to concentrate his mind in prayer until he eats or drinks. And even nowadays, when we do not concentrate so much in prayer, nevertheless if he wants to eat and drink in order to concentrate, he has permission to do so.

See there for sources.

For those wondering if this is the reason for the leniency, regarding Chabad practice specifically see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15900&st=&pgnum=343&hilite=): (emphasis added)

> הנה לא ירעיב את עצמו עד
>    כמה וכמה שעות על היום, אלא ישתה דבר המחזק את הגוף וגם **יאכל מיני
>    מזונות בבקר ואפילו קודם התפלה**. וכבר ידוע פתגם רבוה״ק והוראתם, אז
>    מען־ דארף עסין צוליב דאוונען ניט דאוונען צוליב עסן. וכוונתם היתה ג״כ
>    בפשטות, **שאם הוא רעב בשעת התפלה**, הרי אי אפשר, לאנשים כערכנו —
>    שלא תהי׳ לזה נגיעה בהתבוננות בתפלה והאריכות בה, משא״כ **כשיאכל לפני
>    התפלה יסולק בלבול זה**, וביכולתו - אם רק ברצונו - לעבוד עבודתו
>    ביותר טוב ובאופן נעלה.
>
> ובתור תיקון על אשר נהג עד כמה באומן אחר, הרי ישפיע גם בסביבתו,
>    אשר כל אלו שאינם בריאים ועפמ״ש באגרת התשובה הנ״ל, לא ירעיבו את
>    עצמם, ויתפללו בבקר וגם ילמדו אז נשמה בגוף שאינו מבלבל, והשי״ת
>    יצליחו

Comment: This doesn't say that *m'zonos* food is permitted per se, just that a food is not prohibited before davening on the grounds of גאוה if the person needs it to concentrate (such as fruit or flavored drinks). יש בו משום גאוה ≠ חשיבי לסעודת שבת.

Comment: Would it make a difference if the pre-Shacharit "cookie" was breakfast-like food such as a muffin or doughnut? Maybe oatmeal-riasin and the seuda "cookie" were regulach or brownies or chocolate chip? At least in my part of the world, any type of cookies can be eaten anytime of the day but some are more breakfast like than others just as some foods are, say eggs on a toasted muffin.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I have been told by at least two Orthodox rabbis that one should not eat anything for breakfast on Shabbat unless they will be too hungry if they didnt. If they "have to eat," I'm told it should be something sweet, specifically cake. I imagine cookies would count. But these comments were conveyed by the rabbis in the context of Shabbat, not the week day.

Comment: @Fred, a sick person and a hungry person are equivalent (וכן הצמא והרעב הרי הן בכלל חולים - רמב"ם הלכות תפילה פרק ה ה"ב), and it seems pretty obvious that a sick person wouldn't be limited to only fruit.

Comment: @JJLL, I'm not aware of that distinction. Perhaps ask it as a separate question? The Chabad practice (mentioned in the question here) doesn't distinguish, but there may be other opinions. Go with what your Rabbi is telling you over what you read on the internet.

Comment: @Yishai If the sick person only needs fruit to concentrate on his prayers, why would he be allowed to have Mezonot?

Comment: @Yishai Equivalent with respect to the restriction משום גאוה. Lesser restrictions would seemingly still apply to distractedly hungry people.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the syllogism goes the other way. If a sick person could eat mezonos if they had to, so could a distracted person if they had to. If there is a preference to avoid something that makes a meal (mezonos, bread) if you can get away with something else (for both) is a different question. The bottom line is that the heter is *not* that mezonos isn't really a seuda, it is that it is needed to improve concentration.

Comment: @Yishai You claim that anything a *choleh* can eat, a distracted person can also eat. This would include bread. So you are basically saying that a *se'uda* is permissible before davening if someone is distracted. This is not indicated by the source, which is only comparing a distracted person to a sick person with respect to the prohibition משום גאוה (see *B'rachos* 10b). The general prohibition against being *kove'a s'uda* before performing mitzvos would presumably still apply, and the logic behind a comparison to a sick person is inapplicable in that regard.

Comment: @Fred, that sounds like a different question than the OP - but as Double AA pointed out, the restriction should still apply equally. In other words if the sick person would be healthy without the seuda is the same case as the distracted person being undistracted without the seuda.

Comment: It wasn't a question. It was a criticism of your argument that a *s'uda* (as such) is permissible for a distracted person before *shacharis*. | The comparison you mention is irrelevant to my point, and I think you are reading things into @DoubleAA 's comment that aren't there.

Comment: @Fred, are you saying 1) Mezonos doesn't have a Geius issue, rather a different issue. 2) This is not the heter for Mezonos specifically (if so, why not?). 3) Mezonos has a Geius issue, and an additional different issue which this heter doesn't (necessarily) satisfy. 4) Granted that this is a reason to permit Mezonos vis-a-vis Geius, but that can't be the heter (or the whole heter) because there is still a problem of *kove'a s'uda*?

Comment: @Yishai None of the above, but the closest would be #4. I'm not saying definitively that eating *m'zonos* counts as a *s'uda*. However, if you hold that it does (as is seemingly implied if you eat *m'zonos* after *kiddush*), then #4 comes into play (seemingly making it forbidden to eat *m'zonos* before davening). Conversely, if you eat *m'zonos* before davening you seem to be accepting that there is not a *k'vi'as s'uda* problem with *m'zonos*, and seemingly you should therefore not eat *m'zonos* after *kiddush*. I think this is the question in the OP.

Comment: @Fred, my understanding from [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/32164/cookies-for-kiddush/32168?noredirect=1#comment83937_32164) is that he is asking about Siman 89, which is about geius, not seuda. That is why I asked for clarification before answering. It isn't uncommon for people to think the issur is about kvias suda. Thus my answer - the problem is different. On your question (or the question the way you phrased it) I could answer, but I don't have an immediate source for it. I'll see if I can find one.