Is one ever ALLOWED to make Kidush before Shacharis?
I know that he doesn't NEED to make Kidush, but if one must eat before Shacharis, is he ALLOWED to make Kiddush?

This is my father-in-law's practice. Bli neder I will find a source later.

what is this person eating before shacharit? bread? pat haba'ah beiksanin? other food?

One can eat before shachsris without kiddish

Related (dupe?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32161/6592

@Coreofreality this is not at all so clear, see here and there

Technically you can say the day kiddush anytime you like. It's just pesukim and hagafen. I just came across this, which seems to recommend it for one who must eat before davening. On the other hand, Chabad custom is to eat a little before davening (to aid in concentration), and it seems to be a given that kiddush is not required.

Answer and sources from Halachipedia (https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kiddush)

Someone who is sick and needs to eat before davening on Shabbat,
according to Ashkenazim should recite Kiddush beforehand unless one
doesn't eat a kezayit of mezonot within a kdei achilat pras, while
according to Sephardim it isn't necessary.

Mishna Brurah (Biur Halacha 289:1 s.v. chovat) and Igrot Moshe OC 2:26:2 write that someone who is sick and needs to eat before davening on Shabbat should make kiddush unless he doesn't need to eat pat haba bekisnin. Piskei Teshuvot 289:8 note 63 writes that the best option is for the sick person not to have a kezayit of pat haba bekisnin within a kedi achilat pras which wouldn't obligate kiddush.
Yabia Omer OC 8:31 and Or Letzion 2:20:14 write that someone who is sick and needs to eat before davening on Shabbat does not need to make kiddush. See also Kaf Hachaim 276:28 who is lenient in extenuating circumstances. See Chazon Ovadia (Shabbat v. 2 p. 149) where Rav Ovadia recommends that a sick person who needs to eat bread or pat haba bekisnin before davening should recite kiddush.

This seems to be conflating the issue of eating before davening with eating before kiddush. Can you drink water before davening without kiddush? As far as I understand, the kiddush requirement only takes effect after davening.

Thank you for your comment - I've revised the answer to better address the question
